# cgi-bin 403 forbidden on apache2

Tags: indexing, cgi-bin

I'm trying to load cgi-bin and I keep getting 403 permissions errors.
When I tried to load cgi-bin/index.pl I get 404 page not found.
Project permissions are set with chmod -R 755.

The server is running debian squeeze, apache2, with php5-cgi.

This is the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

error.log:

```
[Mon Jul 30 09:39:30 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze13 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 30 09:50:44 2012] [error] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Question answered in the comments or edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved: changed the bottom section of 000-default to:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> then installed a few missing perl modules and it worked. Was able to open browser to `/localhost/cgi-bin/index.pl`.